# How to parse response with jackson using ktor?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, ktor

***I have this dependencies:***

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version")
```

***And this settings of `ktor` server:***

```
fun Application.configureHTTP() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(AutoHeadResponse)
    install(Routing)
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        register(ContentType.Application.Json, JacksonConverter())
        jackson {
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        }
    }
    install(CORS) {
        method(HttpMethod.Options)
        method(HttpMethod.Put)
        method(HttpMethod.Delete)
        method(HttpMethod.Patch)
        header(HttpHeaders.Authorization)
        header("MyCustomHeader")
//        allowCredentials = true
        anyHost() // @TODO: Don't do this in production if possible. Try to limit it.
    }

}
```

***I'd like to get joke's text about Chuck Norris, so I made this `data classes`:***

```
data class ChuckNorrisJoke(
    val type: String,
    val value: Map<Any, Any>
)

data class JokeContent(
    val id: Long,
    val joke: String,
    val categories: List<String>
)
```

***And eventually this is my function for getting joke:***

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(JsonFeature)
}
suspend fun getChuckNorrisJoke(): ChuckNorrisJoke {
    return client
        .get("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
}
```

***When I call the method, I get this error:***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to find serializer. Consider to add one of the following dependencies: 
 - ktor-client-gson
 - ktor-client-json
 - ktor-client-serialization
    at io.ktor.client.features.json.DefaultJvmKt.defaultSerializer(DefaultJvm.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.client.features.json.JsonFeature$Feature.prepare(JsonFeature.kt:130)
    at io.ktor.client.features.json.JsonFeature$Feature.prepare(JsonFeature.kt:125)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig$install$3.invoke(HttpClientConfig.kt:77)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig$install$3.invoke(HttpClientConfig.kt:74)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install(HttpClientConfig.kt:97)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.kt:172)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.kt:81)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:43)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt.<clinit>(Application.kt:109)
```

**Can't understand how to set `HttpClient` correctly.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version")` dependency declaration is for the **server**. You need to declare one for the **client**: `implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-jackson:$ktor_version"`. You can find more information [here](https://ktor.io/docs/json.html#jvm_dependency).

Comment: Thanks! I ran it with `ktor-client-jackson` and god help (`install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = JacksonSerializer()
    }`).